# How do I list the pages of a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Grouping pages/posts into taxonomies is great IF you can list the pages under each category.

For instance, I have set a taxonomy as 'WordPress Reference'. Then I have a "category" (I think that's what it is) under the taxonomy called "Subject 1".

I have then set two pages to "Subject 1" under WordPress Reference.

Then I created a custom page template with a wp_list_categories command:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy=wordpress-reference'); ?>
```

Now this accomplishes a list of categories but for each category I want to display the list of pages associated with the category. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question:

You can use the loop to query only posts based on a taxonomy & terms :

```
query_posts('taxonomy'='term');
```

& then run the loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo '<h6>'; ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
echo '</h6>';
the_date();
the_excerpt();
```